# Most graceful way to retrieve an item from one of two dictionaries, defaulting to a default value if needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bit of code I was hoping to clean up/shrink down.

I have a function which receives a key and returns the corresponding value from either of two dictionaries, or a default value if the key is present in neither.

Here is a verbose (but explicit) version of the problem:

```
def lookup_function( key ):

    if key.lower() in Dictionary_One: return Dictionary_One[ key.lower ]

    if key.lower() in Dictionary_Two: return Dictionary_Two[ key.lower ]

    return Globally_Available_Default_Value
```

Not horrifying to look at. Just seems a bit voluminous to me.

So, assuming that both dictionaries and the default value are available from the global scope, and that the key must be a string in lowercase, what is the cleanest, shortest, most graceful, and most pythonic way of achieving this?

Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative answer using an "on the fly" mixed dictionary:

```
dict(Dictionary_Two, **Dictionary_One).get(key.lower(), Globally_Available_Default_Value)
```

Comment: Natural idea but 1) it isn't quite the same if there is a duplicate key (your code would retrieve the value from the second dictionary)  and 2) the overhead could be substantial if the dictionaries are large.

Comment: Niceeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: 2) yes indeed, 1) by putting the first dictionary as keywords you override any repeated keys, thus ensuring you get the values from `Dictionary_One` first (although with more than two dictionaries you get a `TypeError`)

Comment: @Mstaino You are right. I didn't see how you put the second dictionary first, thus anticipating my first point. It is a nice idea, though as far as my second point goes, if this is going to be used more than a couple of times OP might be better off just constructing a third dictionary for reuse.

Comment: Yep, but I wanted to point it out as an alternative solution. I think @jdehesa solution is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

You can shorten that to:

```
def lookup_function( key ):
    key = key.lower()
    return Dictionary_One.get(key, Dictionary_Two.get(key, Globally_Available_Default_Value))
```

Comment: Nice. It is so short that there is little reason to abstract it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Lesser/shorter code is not necessarily *better* as there are other considerations, such as generality, reusability, and extensibility.

Raymond Hettinger contributed a recipe to the *Python Cookbook™, Second Edition* for a `Chainmap` class that automates chained dictionary lookups which I think would be a very elegant way of doing what you want (and the class is reusable).

**Update:** Just discovered that the Python 3 `collections` module contains a [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), so it ought to be easier to use it instead of writing your own as shown below.

```
class Chainmap(object):
    def __init__(self, *mappings):
        # record the sequence of mappings into which we must look
        self._mappings = mappings

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # try looking up into each mapping in sequence
        for mapping in self._mappings:
            try:
                return mapping[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        # 'key' not found in any mapping, so raise KeyError exception
        raise KeyError(key)

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        # return self[key] if present, otherwise 'default'
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __contains__(self, key):
        # return True if 'key' is present in self, otherwise False
        try:
            self[key]
            return True
        except KeyError:
            return False
```

Sample usage:

```
dictionary_one = {'key1': 1, 'key2':2}
dictionary_two = {'key2': 3, 'key4':4}

globally_available_default_value = 42
chmap = Chainmap(dictionary_one, dictionary_two)

def lookup_function(key):
    try:
        return chmap[key.lower()]
    except KeyError:
        return globally_available_default_value

print(lookup_function('Key1'))  # -> 1
print(lookup_function('Key2'))  # -> 2
print(lookup_function('Key3'))  # -> 42
print(lookup_function('Key4'))  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers. Here's mine!

```
return { **{ key.lower(): default_value }, **dictionary_one, **dictionary_two }[ key.lower() ];
```

Just requires changing the names a bit to be a little shorter. This method would NOT be recommended for long dictionaries, but is perfectly workable for short ones. dictionary_one would override the default value if it contains the key, with dictionary_two then overriding any keys in dictionary_one.

Not perfect in all cases, but in a for general use this is what I'm going to go with.